# Postman POST Request not going through despite supplying the appropriate Request Body

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, postman

I'm currently working on a SpringBoot project, I have a method SendMoney that takes in 3 parameters: User sender, User recipient and double amount. SendMoney creates a new transaction and stores in the database.

When i tried creating a transaction programmatically in my Main method, it works without issues but on PostMan i keep getting the error below:
[image: RequestBody missing error in PostMan]

I keep getting this RequestBody missing error in Postman despite providing the required RequestBody which are: User sender, User receiver and double amount.

Below is the sendMoney method:

```
@Transactional
    public ApiResponse<Transaction> sendMoney(@NotNull User theSender, @NotNull User recipient, double amount) {

//        if(getCurrentAdmin() == null) {
//            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("No Admin Found");
//        }
        validateSenderReceiver(theSender.getEmail(), recipient.getEmail());

        User sender = findOrCreateUser(theSender);
        User receiver = findOrCreateUser(recipient);

        checkSenderMonthlyLimit(sender, receiver, BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));

        Transaction transaction = initializeTransaction(sender, receiver, amount, generateMTCN());

        transactionRepository.save(transaction);

        return new ApiResponse<>(true, "Transaction saved", transaction);
    }
```

When i post the transaction in my Main method using commandLineRunner, it works fine and the transaction is saved in the database. Here's my code below:

```
@Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner (TransactionService transactionService,
                              AdminService adminService,
                              UserRoleRepository userRoleRepository) {
        return args -> {

            User sender  = User.builder()
                    .firstName("Olamide")
                    .lastName("Thompson")
                    .email("olamide@mail.com")
                    .build();

            User receiver = User.builder()
                    .firstName("Francis")
                    .lastName("Oladosu")
                    .email("francisola@gmail.com")
                    .build();



            transactionService.sendMoney(sender, receiver, 200);
}
}
```

Below is my Get request in Postman to get transactions:
[image: GET Request in Postman]

Please help. Am i sending the request wrongly in Postman? I've tried every possible means to resolve this. I have several other POST requests that's working fine through Postman but this doesn't seem to work.

Here's my TransactionController Post Method:

```
@PostMapping("/send")
    public ApiResponse<Transaction> sendMoney (@RequestBody User sender, @RequestBody User receiver, @RequestBody double amount){
        return transactionService.sendMoney(sender,receiver,amount);
    }
```

Comment: Do not hesitate to accept my answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create Request body dto, like

```
public record CreateTransactionRequestBody(
    User sender,
    User receiver,
    double amount
) {
}
```

And change your **sendMoney** controller method to

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public ApiResponse<Transaction> sendMoney(@RequestBody CreateTransactionRequestBody transactionRequestBody) {
    return transactionService.sendMoney(transactionRequestBody.sender(), transactionRequestBody.receiver(), transactionRequestBody.amount());
}
```

---

**UPD**: if you cannot use ***Java record***, you can use class, in this way it should look like:

```
 public class CreateTransactionRequestBody {
    private User sender;
    private User receiver;
    private double amount;

    public User getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(User sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public User getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(User receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

And your controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public ApiResponse<Transaction> sendMoney(@RequestBody CreateTransactionRequestBody transactionRequestBody) {
    return transactionService.sendMoney(transactionRequestBody.getSender(), transactionRequestBody.getReceiver(), transactionRequestBody.getAmount());
}
```

This should help. Happy coding.